# jquery function is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying submit some form using ajax

```
//include jquery-1.4.2.min.js
var submitForm = document.createElement("FORM");
...
jQuery.post(submitForm.getAttribute('action'), submitForm.serialize(), function(data) {
      bla-bla
});
```

But there is error : "Error: submitForm.serialize is not a function" (FF)

What can I do? Thanks.

Comment: Im create form using javascript.

Comment: @Stas: Create the element using jQuery instead. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Thread will be closed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the form element with jQuery instead.

```
var submitForm = jQuery("<form />");

/* set attributes using attr */

// use attr instead of getAttribute
jQuery.post(submitForm.attr('action'), submitForm.serialize(), function(data) {
      bla-bla
});
```

Comment: Creating element with jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/ --- jQuery attr: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 3):

`submitForm` is a DOM element, so you need to wrap it in a jQuery object to user jQuery methods like [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) on it, like this:

```
jQuery(submitForm).serialize()
```